# "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (%)." but request seems to be fine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, request-validation

ASP.Net MVC 3.0, .NET 4.0, IIS 7

I know it has been asked a many times, but I still can't figure out what's wrong with it.

I get these messages only occasionally (less than 1 a day), and I get about 4k visits daily.

Here is a link to the error report:
http://wowreforge.com/elmah.axd/detail?id=6CBE6DCA-88C2-45E7-AF53-A53061B8E25D

(notice there are links to XML and JSON detailed reports)

First thing to note is URL (PATH) contains UTF-8 encoded character : /US/Warsong/Spartan%C3%B6
second thing, request is **HEAD**, not **GET**
Neither one of those details should result in the error I receive, I think.

The original URL was:
http://wowreforge.com/US/Warsong/Spartan%C3%B6?reforge=--52145254126214646464--3214325254&crit=7&dodge=90&exp=19&haste=1&hit=10&mastery=100&parry=67&spi=0

I have tried this URL with both GET and HEAD request, but wasn't able to reproduce the error.

Anything else I can poke at?

Comment: The link to the error report is not working

Comment: sorry about that. had to recycle the log. Link updated.

Comment: Same issue here - sometimes IIS 7.0 doesn't seem to decode URLs correctly. Do you have the IIS Rewrite Module 2.0 installed? I have a suspicion it may be a bug somewhere in there.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `PATH_TRANSLATED = E:\web\wowreforgec\htdocs\EU\Kael%27Thas\Acekhor`. It looks like the URL encoded character `%27` is not being translated to `'`  before looking up the path of the file on disk. The `%` character is forbidden by the [default configuration of the RequestPathInvalidCharacters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestpathinvalidcharacters.aspx) property, thus the input is considered dangerous and an exception is thrown.

### Edit

The [HttpUtility.UrlDecode(string s)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy.aspx) method should transform `/EU/Kael%27Thas/Acekhor` into `/EU/Kael'Thas/Acekhor`. This method (or one of similar function) should be called at the point where the virtual path is resolved to a physical path. Are you using a custom method to transform the virtual path into a physical path?